# Final or Effectively final confusion

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I'm sure that `variables accessed within inner class, should be declared final or effectively final`. But in the below case I'm confused. I don't know whether or not, I misunderstood.

```
public class MyClass {
    private boolean aBoolean = false;
    private Consumer<Boolean> consumer;
    private Consumer<Validatable> vConsumer; // Validatable is an interface that I wrote

    public MyClass(Consumer<Boolean> c) {
        this.vConsumer = validatable -> aBoolean = validatable.hasErrors();
        this.consumer = c;
    }

    public void process() {
        consumer.accept(this.aBoolean);
    }
}
```

In the above case, I did not get any error. How it is possible? Please help

Comment: The restriction is for local-scoped variables (`aBoolean` is a class property).

Comment: "*should be declared final or effectively final*" Ambiguous wording, so just to make sure: you don't *declare* something as effectively final.

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks a lot. "local-scope" is the thing that I have to remember.

Comment: @madhusdhnn you don't have to remember, the compiler will be very happy to remind you that

Comment: @Eugene Haha. Cool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can see in spec:

> ... starting in Java SE 8, a local class can access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or effectively final. **A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is effectively final.**

It means that `effectively final` is a concept which relates only to variables and parameters. Here we can see that you're working with the field of `MyClass` inside lambda not with variable, it could have more than one assignment.